# How to filter output of a command based on contents of a file in bash?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, xargs

I have a file that contains some numbers (port numbers) and also I have a program that reads a pcap file and prints its streams. How I can grep output of my program based on the port numbers in my file?

Example:

port_numbers.txt:

```
12452
9893
42356
...
```

output of `./prg1 traffic.pcap`:

```
1- 1.1.1.1 - 12452 - 2.2.2.2 - 43124
2- 3.5.1.5 - 9893  - 2.4.7.2 - 5312
3- 7.9.1.1 - 145   - 8.6.5.2 - 8986
4- 4.3.1.1 - 56743 - 8.3.2.4 - 33232
5- 3.4.3.1 - 35612 - 2.5.3.2 - 42356
```

required lines: 1,2 and 5!

As both the pcap and the port_numbers files are really large, I can't use grep manually for every single port, and I need a way to automate the process.

Comment: You are looking for match only in column 3?

Comment: This is not the duplicate of the tagged question! I don't want to save output of my program to a file and after that use grep. I want to do all the process in one step.

Comment: @Inian no dear inian, I may be in column 5 too.

Comment: It is still a duplicate, doing `grep -F -f  port_numbers.txt <(prg1 traffic.pcap)` should solve your problem

Comment: @Inian your solution worked fine. thankyou. How can I do it using `xargs` or `awk`?

Comment: A crude way to do in `Awk` would  be to do `awk 'FNR==NR{pcapInfo[$0]; next}{for (i in pcapInfo) if (i ~ $0) print i}' <(prg1 traffic.pcap) port_numbers.txt`